# How to get ReportLevelFilters?

Tags: c#, azure, filter, powerbi, report

From this [guideline from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to), there is parameter `ReportLevelFilters` to set visual of  exporting PDF.

However, I could not find any C# code to get the list of `ReportLevelFilters`.

How can I get the list so that I can identify it while exporting?

Comment: As per the site's tagging guidelines, please avoid putting tags in your question title unless they are organic to the title (i.e. "Why does X behave differently in C# compared to Java?" is OK, but "C# - Why does X do this?" is not).

Comment: got it, thanks @Llama